# MATLAB: Plotting 1-dimensional data on a 2-dimensional plot

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I am trying to plot some one-dimensional data onto a 2-D plot in MATLAB.

Basically, I have a waveform output and I would like to have vertical lines superposed at relevant data points. At the moment, I am plotting on top of my pre-existing figure with the following code:

```
plot(velocityPeaks(:,1), 0, 'r.');
```

This produces a red dot at y = 0 for each of the positions that 'velocityPeaks' contains a value. I'd prefer to have this as a vertical red line that cuts through the whole graph. Here is my current output:

[image]

Those red dots - at the moment I have to use a ruler against the computer screen to see exactly what they relate to. Not the ideal solution!

Comment: Seconded @OliCharlesworth's suggestion: `stem(velocityPeaks(:,1),velocityPeaks(:,2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
plot(velocityPeaks(:,[1 1]) , ylim,'r-')
```

This will plot a series of vertical lines at the locations of `velocityPeaks(:,1)` at the y limits already contained in the plot.  To specify the limit yourself, use, for example:

```
plot(velocityPeaks(:,[1 1]) , [4 9],'r-')
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you wanted, but whenever I do something like this I like to plot circles on top of original waveform at the peak locations.  So something like this (assuming `velocity` is the original waveform):

```
velocityPeakValues = velocity(velocityPeaks);
plot(velocityPeaks(:,1), velocityPeakValues(:,1), 'ro');
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can use the `data cursor icon` in the figure, and then click on the red points to get its coordinates.